# Converting inputStream from a ZipFile to String

Tags: java, string, inputstream, zip

Here the main functionality of my web application is to upload .zip file and store it at the server side but before doing that I need to do some following task:
1.) .zip file contains the xml file, I have to first validate the xml file using schema.
2.) if the xml file is valid than I need to convert the content of the xml file into string without unzipping the file i.e. from the inputstream.

I am successfull in validating the xml file but I am getting the following exception while converting the string from the inputstream:
**"java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream"**

I have tried all the solutions provided in the Stack Overflow and other forum site but I am not yet successfull. Any help will be really appreciated:

Following is the code:

```
try
    {
        ZipFile zipFileUtil = new ZipFile(zipFile);
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipFileContents = zipFileUtil.entries();
        while(zipFileContents.hasMoreElements())
        {

            ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFileContents.nextElement();
            if(zipEntry.getName().equals("File.xml"))
            {
                InputStream sourceFile = zipFileUtil.getInputStream(zipEntry);
                if(isValidAsPerXSD(sourceFile))
                {
                    //At this line Exception is Generated
                    String xmlContent = IOUtils.toString(sourceFile);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+t.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: "convert the content of the xml file into string without unzipping the file" is meaningless. There is no XML file until you unzip the input. Please try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read the stream "sourceFile" twice !
An input stream is supposed to be read sequentially to the end. You must close it and reopen it.

```
InputStream sourceFile = zipFileUtil.getInputStream(zipEntry);
if(isValidAsPerXSD(sourceFile))
{
    sourceFile.close();
    sourceFile = zipFileUtil.getInputStream(zipEntry);
    //At this line Exception is Generated
    String xmlContent = IOUtils.toString(sourceFile);
}
sourceFile.close();
```

Comment: you could also reset the stream

Comment: AWESOME.......it worked thanks @Lotfi. So the conclusion is that I need to work really hard to improve my CORE concepts.. :) thanks again

Comment: @kromit: I'm not sure the ZipInputStream supports reset. If it does, then reseting it is the right way to go :)

Comment: @Lotfi: it does -> FilterInputStream